# How I can solve an error 400 appearing at google console?

Tags: google-search-console, google-crawlers

We are having crawling error code *400* at *Webmaster Tools* by google .

We were implementing 3rd party ads, and the crawler took the link and added the macro after it. To make it clear, let's say we have `www.name.com/stackoverflow`, and the error 400 appears because the url is changed to

```
www.name.com/stackoverflow/%%CLICK_URL_UNESC%%http%3A//bs.serving-sys.com/BurstingPipe/adServer.bs%3Fcn%3Dbrd%26FlightID%3D25387941%26Page%3D%26PluID%3D0%26Pos%3D1547945272
```

How we can solve this or block google from getting these links out our sie but without harming the original link?

Comment: I attempted to improve the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix the link. Both versions of the link you posted are invalid because they have an invalid prefix.

They need to start with `http://` or `https://` or just `//`.